# How can I move a table downward in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

Is it possible to move a table downward in Java. I tried `setBorder`, `setLocation`, ... but it didn't work. What should I do?

```java
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter proper data: ");
label.setBounds(0, 0, 120, 50);
frame.add(label);
JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
btn.setBounds(100, 300, 80, 50);
frame.add(btn);
String data [][] = new String [6][4];
String column[]={"No.","Player 1","Player 2","Strategy"};         
JTable table = new JTable(data, column);
JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table);
frame.add(sp);          
frame.setSize(300,400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Please look at this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Looks good for a `BorderLayout` for the outer panel (outlined in blue). The big red label goes in the `PAGE_START` and the (scroll pane of the) table goes in the `CENTER`.

Put the button in a panel with a `FlowLayout` (centered), the panel with the red outline, in the `PAGE_END` of the border layout. Done.

All extra height (if the user makes the GUI bigger) will be given to the table.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code based on @AndrewThompson suggestion and result was good.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Play");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter proper data: ");
    JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
    String data [][] = new String [100][4];
    String column[]={"No.","Player 1","Player 2","Strategy"};
    JTable table = new JTable(data, column);
    JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table);
    topPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    topPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    topPanel.add(btn, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    outerPanel.add(topPanel);
    frame.add(outerPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

Comment: 1) `frame.pack();` Nice! 2) `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` I prefer `setLocationByPlatform(true);`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for demo code and screenshots of the effect.